# Einstein Bot - Passing boolean into Apex action

Tags: apex, einstein, invocable-method, einstein-chatbot, invocablevariable

I need to pass boolean value (NOT asked to the customer) to apex action and need to hard code it. I have an invocable method which takes a list parameters like (psuedo code)

```
public class SomeClass{
 @InvocableMethod(Label='Do Something')
 public static List<Id> provideProcessedResult( List<InputParam> input) { 
   ...
   return List<Id>;
 }

 public class InputParam{
   @InvocableVariable 
   public String contactIds;

   @InvocableVariable(Label='Send SMS')
   public Boolean sendViaSMS;
 }
}
```

I am not sure what I need to pass to sendSMS, should it be true/1/TRUE? I tried all these values in variation but it doesn't seem to work. I get the below error

*Error when invoking /support/conversations/0X93G0000004C9c/invocations/0SC3G0000004CJkWAM: [{"actionName":"SomeClass","errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_INPUT","message":"Unable to convert value '1' to Apex type Boolean for Apex action SomeClass Variable sendViaSMS","fields":[]}],"isSuccess":false,"outputValues":null}]*

It's not able to convert true/1/True to Apex type boolean true, anyone have a clue how I could sort this or what should be passed for it to be evaluated to true (I tried {!true} as well but that doesn't work either)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue and our workaround is just to create the variable as String and then parse it inside the apex method.